# How to make notification button call function in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-button

I'm beginner in adroid. I know that addaction method make button. But every example code call intent with view. I want to call function without view. exactly I want to execute other app when I press button. Is there like onclick method in notification?

Comment: This is available through the Intent. You can play with category, or use direct package name or process to communicate with other apps.

Comment: The app I would execute through notification provides only url scheme for passing the argument. And the argument is changed according to index variable.